# Merging python lists of length a, b, c, .... to create a list of length a*b*c*

Tags: python

I have two python objects as follows:

```
data1 = [{"key1": i} for i in range(331)]
data2 = [{"key2": i} for i in range(4)]
```

I have created a merged object like this:

```
merged_data = []
for item_a in data1:
    for item_b in data2:
        merged_data.append({**item_a, **item_b})
```

However, if a variable called `data` is created with `n` objects in it as follows,

```
data1 = [{"key1": i} for i in range(331)]
data2 = [{"key2": i} for i in range(4)]
.
.
.
.
dataN = [{"keyN" : i} for i in range(n)]

data = [data1, data2, .... dataN]
```

from the variable called `data`, how to get a merged list like this?

```
[{'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, ...., "keyN" : 0},
 {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, ...., "keyN" : 1},
 {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, ...., "keyN" : 2},
 {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, ...., "keyN" : 3},
 {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, ...., "keyN" : 4},
 .
 .
 .
 .
 {'key1': 330, 'key2': 3,...., "keyN" : n}]
```

Comment: I believe this is effectively a duplicate of [How to get the Cartesian product of multiple lists](/q/533905/4518341) and [How to convert list of dictionaries to dictionary](/q/51149822/4518341), though the second one's answers are a bit lacking. See also [How do I merge **two** dictionaries in a single expression in Python?](/q/38987/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Itertools to the rescue:

> [`itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
>
> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

Given your `data`, `itertools.product(*data)` is an iterator that yields tuples like `({'key1': 0}, {'key2': 0}, ...., {"keyN" : 0})`, so then you simply have to merge them. Given an iterable we can "merge" all those items using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). We can use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.ior) module to get a function version of `a |= b`, which is used to merge dictionaries in-place.

We can use the third argument to `reduce` to insert them into a fresh dictionary.

Putting it all together:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import product
from operator import ior

merged_list = [reduce(ior, dictionaries, {}) for dictionaries in product(*data)]
```

Comment: `ior` might be better.

Comment: @nocomment How's that? It doesn't seem like OP wants to modify their input data, if that's what you mean.

Comment: `for first_dict, *rest`, then pass `first_dict.copy()` as the third argument to `reduce`?

Comment: I meant `reduce(ior, dictionaries, {})`.

Comment: Good suggestion, @nocomment. Either would work but `reduce(ior, dictionaries, {})` is very likely to be much more performant.

Comment: One advantage that `or_` had was that you could've done `merged_list = list(map(reduce, repeat(or_), product(*data)))`, avoiding Python looping. But that's just a silly game I keep playing. The list comprehension is clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your answers. I followed this approach to get the results. Cheers

```
mergedDat = []
for values in itertools.product(*data):
    mergedDict = {}
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        mergedDict.update(value)
    mergedDat.append(mergedDict)
```